# MongoDB - Convert values of each object in array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

So I have documents following this structure :

```js
username: "JohnDoe"
activities: [
    {
        name: "tennis",
        lastTime: <number>
    },
    {
        name: "soccer",
        lastTime: <number>
    }

]
```

I want to convert the "lastTime" field from number to date in each activity object of my document.

I already did convert number into date in the past but it was a direct field like this :

```js
name: "Thomas",
birthday: <number>
```

I used this query :

```js
db.coll.updateOne({name: "Thomas"},[{$set: {"birthday": {$toDate: "$birthday"}}}])
```

but if I try something similar now like :

```js
db.coll.updateOne({username: "JohnDoe"},[{$set: {"activities.lastTime": {$toDate: "$activities.lastTime"}}}])
```

It returns "Unsupported conversion from array to date in $convert with no onError value".
I kind of get it but I don't know what do to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I kept digging and found that I needed to use $map.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/

Here is it :

```js
db.coll.updateOne(
    {username: "JohnDoe"},
    [{$set: {
        "activities": {
            $map: {
                input: "$activities",
                in: {
                    name: "$$this.name",
                    lastTime: {$toDate: "$$this.lastTime"},
                }
            }
        }
    }}]
)
```

**EDIT :**

Or better, if I just want to change the "lastTime" field :

```js
db.coll.updateOne(
    {username: "JohnDoe"},
    [{$set: {
        "activities": {
            $map: {
                input: "$activities",
                in: {
                    $mergeObjects: ["$$this",{lastTime: {$toDate: "$$this.lastTime"}}]
                }
            }
        }
    }}]
)
```